# [gazebo-2] process has died [pid 25662, exit code -11]

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to run the simulation http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo,but it gives me error message as follows. seems it is a GUI rendering problem? Is it related to graphic drivers? I am using a Lenovo t410 notebook with Ubuntu 10.04.

The gazebo-2 process died but the log file is empty. The exit code sometimes will be 255.

/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreCreator.cc:441 : Exception: Unable to create the rendering window

/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:261 : Exception: Error loading the GUI
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreCreator.cc:441 : Exception: Unable to create the rendering window

Error Loading Gazebo
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:261 : Exception: Error loading the GUI
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreCreator.cc:441 : Exception: Unable to create the rendering window

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 25662, exit code -11].
log files: /home/btian/.ros/log/d469a558-376d-11e1-bcb0-f0def113b3f6/gazebo-2*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12527/%5Bgazebo-2%5D-process-has-died-%5Bpid-25662,-exit-code--11%5D./) by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 710 on 2012-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-04**:
@tianb03 : Hi, can you check your /tmp folder for a gazebo folder. Try deleting it and then running the simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/2152/system-requirements-for-rviz-and-gazebo) question for some information regarding graphics drivers. Additionally, many Lenovo computers come with Optimus (two graphics cards). This does not play well with Ubuntu. Consider disabling one card.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2012-05-24**:
thanks. I am away for quite a while. but this does help me.